# retrieve letter from string in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

With the following C-function, I want to retrieve the letter at index idx from some string:

```
char get_letter(char *str, int idx)
{
    return *(str + idx);
}
```

For example, the following:

```
char s[] = "Barack";
get_letter(s,2);
```

should return the letter 'r'.

Here is the whole program (name of the executable file is "retrieve"):

```
int printf(const char * restrict, ...);
char get_letter(char *, int);

int main(int carg, const char **varg){
  if (carg != 2) return -1;  
  printf("%s", get_letter(varg[1],1));
  return 0;           
}

char get_letter(char *str, int idx)
{
return *(str + idx);
}
```

when I run the program (e.g.: ./retrieve test), instead of getting the letter "e", I get an error message ("Segmentation fault: 11").
What is going wrong here?

Comment: The fault must lie in the way you print the result: your example code throws away the answer. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. When I `printf("%c\n", get_letter(s,2));` the result is the expected `'r'`.

Answer (score 1):

The possible print a character in C language as follows:

```
char c = 'j';
printf("%c",j);
```

Working  code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char get_letter(char *str, int idx)
{
    return *(str + idx);
}

int main()
{
    char s[] = "Barack";
    printf("%c", get_letter(s,2));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it ... it has to be %c instead of %s in the print function.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a char* but your return type is char. 
Change your return statement to `return str[idx];`

Also why you need a function for that? you can just write `s[idx]`. I am curious about the reason.